# Не получается конструкция if-elif-else

Tags: python, python-3.x, if, условия

```
print("Система расчёта штрафов в Германии")

carSpeed = 70
isTown = True

fineFor1to10 = 15
fineFor11to15 = 25
fineFor16to20 = 35
fineFor21andMore = 80

townSpeed = 60
countrySpeed = 90

if isTown:
    overSpeed = carSpeed - townSpeed
else:
    overSpeed = carSpeed - countrySpeed

if overSpeed >= 1 and overSpeed < 10:
    message_template = "You've got a fine! {des} euro!"
    message = message_template.format(des=fineFor1to10)
    print(message)
elif overSpeed >= 11 and overSpeed < 15:
    message_template1 = "You've got a fine! {des} euro!"
    message1 = message_template1.format(des=fineFor11to15)
    print(message1)
elif overSpeed >= 16 and overSpeed < 20:
    message_template2 = "You've got a fine! {des} euro!"
    message2 = message_template2.format(des=fineFor16to20)
    print(message2)
elif overSpeed >21:
    message_template3 = "You've got a fine! {des} euro!"
    message3 = message_template3.format(des=fineFor21andMore)
    print(message3)
```

Ошибки не выдаёт, но сообщения не печатает. А с else в конце вместо elif всегда пишет только последнее message3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас значение переменной `OverSpeed` = 10 (70-60)
Никакое из условий

```
if overSpeed >= 1 and overSpeed < 10:


elif overSpeed >= 11 and overSpeed < 15:


elif overSpeed >21:
```

Не выполняется.

Замените `if overSpeed >= 1 and overSpeed < 10:` на `if overSpeed >= 1 and overSpeed <= 10:`